# Excel VBA MarkerStyle

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change series marker style into crosses X.

I have created test script in new excel file with:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleX
```

and it works fine. I have:

```
    Worksheets("RecordID Chart").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).Name = lo.ListColumns("RecordID").DataBodyRange.Rows(1)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).XValues = tesPercentage
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).Values = testError
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleX
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).MarkerSize = 5
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = myCol & graph
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).Select
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Actually, it is cross, but it is not displayed as a cross:

[image]

So I believe it has some problems with Marker Fill or Marker Line Color... I am still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this will serve the purpose:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleX
    .MarkerSize = 7
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your marker fill color is the same as the marker foreground color.  You'll need to change it.

Comment: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 2` I have added this, and expected that this will solve it, but I have the same issue

Comment: Did you try to change it using the built in dialog as well?

Comment: That sounds something different, could you be more specific about it please?

Comment: Try going to the graph and changing the marker fill by right clicking.

Comment: If I set Marker fill to white, then cross and background disappears. Very strange, I just need to get rid of background color...

Comment: Forst of all, you need to set the background to Nothing and not white.  Second, you set the forground color to white in your code with the line: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(graph + 2).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 2